# how to load javascript before css

Tags: javascript

I have displayed a loading bar before the entire page is loaded on my website.
Here is the js which i am using
[JsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/huyusu/3/edit?html,css,js,output)

Now the problem is when some one opens the web page , black background (css) appears and after 2-3 seconds loading bar shows the loading. Though this is the first script which loads on the website.
Why loading bar gets delay. How can i load it dynamically ?
This is [my website](http://www.cardmart.tk) .   Script name is javatest.js
Sorry if i missed anything ,   i am just a newbie

Comment: I think CSS loads asynchronously from JavaScript, because normally they don’t depend on each other.

Comment: So is there anyway  to load both java & css  together?

Comment: Java is not JavaScript. What do you mean by “together”? If they load asynchronously, they already load together. If you want your JS to load before the CSS, you have to load your CSS _via JS_.

Comment: Ohkay please can you tell me how to do that .  CSS & JS  in the above link

Comment: One of the answers at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14028113/4642212) may be helpful. Basically you just need to append a `<link>` element with the URL to your CSS as the `href` attribute. You can do that at some specific point in your JavaScript where the loading bar finishes, for example. I’m still not quite sure how this is a _problem_, though.

Comment: i did the same way as shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/574944/how-to-load-up-css-files-using-javascript/577002#577002) . 
But still the same delay

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments it looks like you're after loading CSS via your JavaScript. This has been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/577002/3303963). I'm not sure if this will work with JSBin or not, so I suggest you test this in notepad or something else.

Comment: Yea I followed your link , Did the same way as shown in the answer , I could load the css from js but still loading bar shows up after 2-3 seconds.
Still the same thing .

Comment: @wordpressuser Is your actual goal to _reduce the delay_ of the _loading bar first appearing_, regardless of when the CSS loads?

Comment: Yes Sir , thats what i want , as soon as some one opens the page, he should see the loading bar.